# Qual a diferença entre memcpy e snprintf

Tags: c, c++

Estou vendo pessoas usarem snprintf quando eu usaria memcpy. Inclusive fiz alguns testes e funcionou com memcpy.
Agora fiquei na dúvida do porque usar uma e não a outra. E qual o real significado das duas.

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo, um contexto? Realmente pode usar em certos casos, o ideal é usar dentro da semântica pretendida, quando ambos atendem igual.

Answer (score 3):

Ambas as funções possuem propósitos bem distintos e não são equivalentes. Uma não é capaz de substituir a outra sem uma implementação adicional.

O propósito da função `snprintf()` é formatar [strings terminadas em zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

O propósito da função `memcpy()` é copiar o conteúdo de uma dada posição de memória para outra.

Se você usar `memcpy()` para manipular strings, você vai precisar garantir que o terminador `\0` ou `NULL` esteja presente no final da string pois `memcpy()` não garante isso.

A função `memcpy()` é bastante primitiva, enquanto `snprintf()` possui uma implementação mais elaborada, capaz de interpretar as diretivas da `string de formatação` possibilitando conversões de tipos, de bases numéricas, etc.

Já vi cenários (horríveis) onde a função `snprintf()` era usada para se copiar strings:

```
snprintf( dst, strlen(orig), orig );   /* Não faça isso! */
```

Todo esse *gato* pode ser substituido por apenas:

```
strcpy( dest, orig );
```

Que, por incrível que pareça, é equivalente a:

```
memcpy( dest, orig, strlen(orig) + 1 ); /* Não, não, não! */
```

Será que você não está em algum tipo de cenário horrível por aí ?

Comment: melhor usar `strncpy`  do que ensinar a turma a escrever código inseguro com `strcpy` só por que "é mais fácil aprender assim".

Answer (score 2):

Não são a mesma coisa.

A função memcpy copia n bytes a partir da posição de memória apontada pelo primeiro parâmetro para as posições a partir do endereço do segundo parâmetro.

A função snprintf escreve a partir da posição de memória indicada efetuando as formatações definidas no parâmetro.